# Adicionar atributo CSS quando input for selecionado via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, formulário

Estou Fazendo uma aplicação de validação de respostas para determinada pergunta,  necessito que quando o `<input type="checkbox">` for selecionado seja adicionada um atributo`box-shadow` a `<textarea>` da resposota.

O que eu tentei fazer no JQuery nao surgiu efeito no formulario.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("input.correta").is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest("textarea").css("box-shadow", "1px 1px 10px #0c6f00");
    } else {
      $(this).closest("textarea").css("box-shadow", "none");
    }
  });
</script>
```

código HTML

```
  <div class='form-group respostas' id='resposta1'>
<div class='row form-control'>
  <div class='span8'>
    <textarea style='resize:none' class='span8' rows='3' placeholder="1º Resposta" maxlength='255' id='resposta1'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<span class='help-block text-right'>
  <label class='btn btn-success'>
    <input type='checkbox' style='margin-top:0px' class="correta" name='resposta' value='resposta1'> Marcar como Correta
  </label> 
</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa capturar o [evento](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.correta').on('change', function() {
  
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $('#resposta1 .span8').css("box-shadow", "1px 1px 10px #0c6f00");
        } else {
          $('#resposta1 .span8').css("box-shadow", "none");
      }
  })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group respostas' id='resposta1'>
<div class='row form-control'>
  <div class='span8'>
    <textarea style='resize:none' class='span8' rows='3' placeholder="1º Resposta" maxlength='255' id='resposta1'></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<span class='help-block text-right'>
  <label class='btn btn-success'>
    <input type='checkbox' style='margin-top:0px' class="correta" name='resposta' value='resposta1'> Marcar como Correta
  </label> 
</span></div>
```

[EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/qhsdc0db/1/) no jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Cria uma classe CSS

```
.sombra-textarea{    
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #0c6f00
}
```

E no jquery utilize addClass e removeClass

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("input.correta").is(":checked")) {
      $('#resposta1').addClass("sombra-textarea");
    } else {
      $('#resposta1').removeClass("sombra-textarea");
    }
  });
```

Comment: lembrando que para funcionar em todos os navegadores, importante inserir -webkit-box-shadow e -moz-box-shadow: